# PuTTY colour scheme from command line

Tags: command-line, putty, colors

I have putty set up to use the monokai colour scheme via a .reg file found [here](https://gist.github.com/gdvalle/4187089)

This works when creating new SSH sessions using the GUI. However, sometimes I like to start PuTTY from the command line instead:

```
C:\putty.exe -ssh user@ip -pw password
```

When I try to connect using that method the colour scheme no longer loads and defaults to the base PuTTY colour scheme, which I find fairly unusable

Whats the correct way to set the PuTTY colour scheme to monokai, so that it will load correctly regardless of which method is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set color scheme from command-line.

But you can save your preferred color scheme to the "Default Settings" in PuTTY. It will then be picked up for the ad-hoc sessions invoked from a command-line.

- Configure your preferred defaults on the PuTTY configuration window
  (or just load the imported "monokai" session);
- Go to "Session" page;
- Select "Default Settings";
- Press "Save"